# concurrent modification exception linked hash map android

Tags: android, concurrentmodification, linkedhashmap

I am using iterator to delete item from linked hash map but getting concurrent modification exception

```
Iterator<Integer> it = linkedMap.keySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        java.lang.Integer key = it.next();
        if (key.equals(number)) {
            linkedMap.remove(key);
        }
    }
```

Please Help..

Comment: You need call it.remove(); insted linkedMap.remove(key);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `iterator` when check for condition not the `linkedMAp`

```
 Iterator<Integer> it = linkedMap.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
     Integer key = it.next();
        if (key.equals(number)) {
           // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
            it.remove();
        }
    }
```

check also this question is just like yours

[Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-list-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-removing)